# How to clone specific submodules from Boost using cmake

Tags: boost, cmake, git-submodules

I know how to install Boost with the `b2` command and specify only to install the filesystem library. The Boost directory has many contents that I won't need, and it takes a long time to clone all submodules. I have this cmake file to download, build and install Boost. But I don't know how to specify which submodules I want to clone in the `CMakeLists.txt`. I'm using `ExternalProject_add` to download, build, and install Boost.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
include(ExternalProject)
# Download boost from git

SET (BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/boost/src/boost/lib/filesystem/include/boost/)
SET (BOOST_URL https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git )
get_filename_component(BOOST_STATIC_LIBRARIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/libboost_filesystem.a ABSOLUTE)

if ( UNIX )     
    SET (BOOST_STATIC_LIBRARIES ${BOOST_BUILD}/libboost_filesystem.a) 
endif ()

ExternalProject_Add(
boost
PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/boost
GIT_REPOSITORY ${BOOST_URL}

UPDATE_COMMAND ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=filesystem,system 
CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
BUILD_COMMAND ./b2 link=static install --exec-prefix=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/ --includedir=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/boost/
BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

set(BOOST_LIBRARIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
message ("${BOOST_STATIC_LIBRARIES}")
```

---

**EDIT**

I now have the following `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
include(ExternalProject)
# Download boost from git
SET (BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/boost/src/boost/lib/filesystem/include/boost/)
SET (BOOST_URL https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git )
get_filename_component(BOOST_STATIC_LIBRARIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/libboost_filesystem.a ABSOLUTE)

if ( UNIX )     
    SET (BOOST_STATIC_LIBRARIES ${BOOST_BUILD}/libboost_filesystem.a) 
endif ()

ExternalProject_Add(
boost
PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/boost
GIT_REPOSITORY ${BOOST_URL}
GIT_SUBMODULES libs/assert libs/utility libs/config libs/predef libs/system libs/detail libs/filesystem  tools/boostdep tools/build tools/bcp tools/boostbook tools/inspect tools/litre tools/quickbook tools/auto_index
UPDATE_COMMAND ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=filesystem,system 
CONFIGURE_COMMAND ./b2 headers
BUILD_COMMAND ./b2 link=static install
CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib
BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

set(BOOST_LIBRARIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
message ("${BOOST_STATIC_LIBRARIES}")
```

But I get this error message:

```
...patience...
...found 925 targets...
...updating 337 targets...
common.mkdir /usr/local/include/boost
mkdir: Unable to create directory "/usr/local/include/boost": Permission denied.

    mkdir -p "/usr/local/include/boost"

...failed common.mkdir /usr/local/include/boost...
```

But in the cmake file I use this:

```
CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib
```

To install in a different directory than root.
But it does not seem to be working.

---

**EDIT 2:**

I got how to install in a different directory than root. But it seems that has another problem, because the same problem than before happens. What can I do?

I added this:

```
UPDATE_COMMAND ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=filesystem,system --includedir=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/


cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
include(ExternalProject)
# Download boost from git
SET (BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/boost/src/boost/lib/filesystem/include/boost/)
SET (BOOST_URL https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git )
get_filename_component(BOOST_STATIC_LIBRARIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/libboost_filesystem.a ABSOLUTE)

if ( UNIX )     
    SET (BOOST_STATIC_LIBRARIES ${BOOST_BUILD}/libboost_filesystem.a) 
endif ()

ExternalProject_Add(
boost
PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/boost
GIT_REPOSITORY ${BOOST_URL}
GIT_SUBMODULES libs/assert libs/utility libs/config libs/predef libs/system libs/detail libs/filesystem  tools/boostdep tools/build tools/bcp tools/boostbook tools/inspect tools/litre tools/quickbook tools/auto_index
UPDATE_COMMAND ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=filesystem,system --includedir=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/
CONFIGURE_COMMAND ./b2 headers
BUILD_COMMAND ./b2 link=static install
CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib
BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

set(BOOST_LIBRARIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
message ("${BOOST_STATIC_LIBRARIES}")
```

Comment: Have you checked `ExternalProject_Add` [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/ExternalProject.html)? There is *GIT_SUBMODULES* option.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I saw this before make this question >>https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html and here didn't have anythig about it. Thanks!

Comment: I'd probably use `GIT_TAG` as well, and peg it to some know good release of Boost (and update the CMake when new version is release and you have a chance to test it). Following the master branch would be a bit too adventurous IMHO.

Comment: I edited my question. I'm getting install the specific submodules, but I have a problem with install de libraries in a different directorie than root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How I solved my problem:
Download the specifics submodules using the

> GIT_SUBMODULES option

Install the boost in a different directory using and only install the statically version

> BUILD_COMMAND ./b2 link=static install --libdir=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib

And also: installed the specifics binaries using:

> UPDATE_COMMAND ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=filesystem,system,regex,program_options --includedir=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include

```
cmake_minimum_required ( VERSION 2.8.7 )

# Download boost from git

include(ExternalProject)

if ( UNIX )

   if (NOT Boost)

  SET (Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include/boost/)
  SET (Boost_LIBRARIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib )
  SET (BOOST_URL https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git )
  SET (BOOST_BUILD ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}) 
  SET (FILESYSTEM_STATIC_LIBRARIES ${BOOST_BUILD}/lib/libboost_filesystem.a) 
  SET (SYSTEM_STATIC_LIBRARIES ${BOOST_BUILD}/lib/libboost_system.a)
  SET (REGEX_STATIC_LIBRARIES ${BOOST_BUILD}/lib/libboost_regex.a)
  SET (PROGRAM_OPTIONS_STATIC_LIBRARIES ${BOOST_BUILD}/lib/libboost_program_options.a)

  ExternalProject_Add( Boost
    PREFIX Boost
    GIT_REPOSITORY ${BOOST_URL}
    GIT_SUBMODULES  libs/asio libs/date_time libs/config libs/core  libs/detail  libs/io libs/iterator libs/predef libs/preprocessor  libs/smart_ptr libs/throw_exception libs/system libs/filesystem  libs/integer tools/build tools/bcp libs/serialization libs/interprocess libs/tokenizer libs/algorithm libs/program_options  libs/regex  libs/static_assert  libs/thread  libs/utility libs/numeric libs/range libs/array libs/bind libs/concept_check libs/lexical_cast libs/math libs/functional libs/assert libs/type_traits libs/mpl libs/move libs/container libs/any libs/type_index libs/function

    UPDATE_COMMAND ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=filesystem,system,regex,program_options --includedir=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ./b2 headers
    BUILD_COMMAND ./b2 link=static install --libdir=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
  )

  ADD_LIBRARY (Boost_LIB STATIC IMPORTED DEPENDS Boost)  
  SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES (Boost_LIB PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${FILESYSTEM_STATIC_LIBRARIES})
  SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES (Boost_LIB PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${SYSTEM_STATIC_LIBRARIES})
  SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES (Boost_LIB PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${REGEX_STATIC_LIBRARIES})
  SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES (Boost_LIB PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROGRAM_OPTIONS_STATIC_LIBRARIES}) 

   endif()
endif()
```